How well TimescaleDB supports custom types based on standard interger types like timestamp9?
There is a handy PostgreSQL extension timestamp9 that defined a type with the same name which is internally just bigint. I'm curious how well TimescaleDB support timestamp9 time in particular whether it understands that it is just a bigint and applies all the same logic or it treat it as a custom type (thus miss things like highly optimized integer compression etc)?
